# Laravel 8 Datatables Eager Loading Not Working (Yajra)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, yajra-datatable

I am using **Yajra Datatables** to fetch the data inside my table.

I need to display the data of the table `accreditors` wherein the `nonofficial_category_id` column for the said table should display the `area_name` equivalent of it from another database table `non_officials_categories`.

Here is the `Accreditors` Model showing its relationship with `NonOfficialsCategories` Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Accreditors extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = "accreditors";

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'official_category_id',
        'subcategory',
        'position',
        'photo',
    ];

    protected $dates = [
        'deleted_at',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at'
    ];

    public function nonOfficialsCategories()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(NonOfficialsCategories::class, 'nonofficial_category_id');
    }
}
```

Here is the method `indexDatatables` inside `AccreditorsController` which would display the datatable:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Accreditors;
use App\Models\NonOfficialsCategories;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class AccreditorsController extends Controller
{

    public function indexDatatables()
    {
        $model = Accreditors::with('nonOfficialsCategories')->select('accreditors.*');

        if (request()->ajax()) {
            return datatables()->of($model)
                ->addColumn('action', function ($data) {
                    return $this->getActionColumn($data);
                })
                ->rawColumns(['action'])
                ->make(true);
        }
        $categoryCount = NonOfficialsCategories::count();
        return view('personnels.nonofficials.accreditors.datatables.datatables')->with('categoryCount', $categoryCount);
    }
}
```

Here is the `NonOfficialsCategories` Model showing its relationship with `Accreditors` Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class NonOfficialsCategories extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = "non_officials_categories";

    protected $fillable = [
        'area_number',
        'area_name',
        'subcategory',
        'is_accreditor_head',
        'is_taskforce_head',
        'is_auditor',
        'use_counter',
    ];

    protected $dates = [
        'deleted_at',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at'
    ];

    public function taskforces()
    {
        return $this->has(TaskForces::class);
    }
    public function accreditors()
    {
        return $this->has(Accreditors::class);
    }
}
```

Here is the excerpt of the `.blade` file for the accreditors:

```
<div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="row">
        <table class="poppins-normal text-md" id="accreditorsDatatables">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    {{-- <th class="text-white">Id</th> --}}
                    <th class="text-white">Name</th>
                    <th class="text-white">Area Name</th>
                    <th class="text-white">Subcategory</th>
                    <th class="text-white">Position</th>
                    <th class="text-white">Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready( function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }   
        });
        $('#accreditorsDatatables').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: '{!! route("accreditors-datatables") !!}',
            columns: [
                // {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
                {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
                {data: 'nonofficial_category_id', name: 'nonOfficialsCategories.area_name'},
                {data: 'subcategory', name: 'subcategory'},
                {data: 'position', name: 'position'},
                {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false},
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the current (and wrong) display of the datatables as it is:

```
__________________________________________________________________________
|name     |area name        |subcategory     |position      |actions     |
__________________________________________________________________________
|         |1 //wrong        |                |              |            |
__________________________________________________________________________
|         |2 //wrong        |                |              |            |
__________________________________________________________________________
|         |3 //wrong        |                |              |            |
__________________________________________________________________________
```

wherein the display should be:

```
__________________________________________________________________________
|name     |area name        |subcategory     |position      |actions     |
__________________________________________________________________________
|         |Area I //right   |                |              |            |
__________________________________________________________________________
|         |Area II //right  |                |              |            |
__________________________________________________________________________
|         |Area III //right |                |              |            |
__________________________________________________________________________
```

My mistake might be the following:

- Wrong eloquent relationship for the Model files.
- Wrong syntax declaration on the `.blade` section in the `columns` array of the `script` section.
- Wrong syntax declaration on the `indexDatatables` method for the `AccreditorsController`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking out my mistake, I found the solution.

I need to add another `addColumn()` API on the `indexDatatables()`:

```
public function indexDatatables()
    {
        $model = Accreditors::with('nonOfficialsCategories')->select('accreditors.*');

        if (request()->ajax()) {
            return datatables()->of($model)
                ->addColumn('action', function($data) {
                    return $this->getActionColumn($data);
                })
                ->addColumn('area_name', function (Accreditors $accreditors) { // the added column
                    return $accreditors->nonOfficialsCategories->area_name;
                }) 
                ->rawColumns(['action'])
                ->make(true);
        }
        $categoryCount = NonOfficialsCategories::count();
        return view('personnels.nonofficials.accreditors.datatables.datatables')->with('categoryCount', $categoryCount);
    }
```

Then I could just use the following line on the `script` section of the `.blade` file:

```
// format {data: 'name_parameter_in_add_column', name: 'relationshipName.column_name_to_be_searched'},

{data: 'area_name', name: 'nonOfficialsCategories.nonofficial_category_id'},

// the 'area_name' in the script section should be the same name declared in the first parameter of the "addColumn()" API
```

[Here is the link for the documentation reference.](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/8.0/relationships)

Now, I could still be wrong on the relationship declaration because I still confuse myself on the usage of `belongsTo()/belongsToMany()` API. If someone could correct me, I would appreciate it.